# How to exclude rows in which column one and two have the same value?

Tags: linux, shell, select, awk, duplicates

I have a file with some rows with the same name (col 1, eg gph ans stp) but in the col 2 maximum value and exclude the others rows in linux (shell, eg awk grep perl)

For example:

```
col1 | col2 | col3   | col4
------+------+--------+-----------
ghp  | 25   | data1  | otherdata1
ghp  | 23   | data2  | otherdata2
ghp  | 23   | data3  | otherdata3
jkl  | 58   | data4  | otherdata4
stp  | 42   | data5  | otherdata5
stp  | 41   | data6  | otherdata6
stp  | 41   | data7  | otherdata7
```

result

```
 col1 | col2 | col3   | col4
 ------+------+--------+-----------
 ghp  | 25   | data1  | otherdata2
 jkl  | 58   | data4  | otherdata4
 stp  | 42   | data5  | otherdata7
```

In the same file I have some rows with the same name (col 1, eg ghi ans stu) and in the col 2 the same values, I want to exclude these rows in linux (shell, eg awk grep perl)

For example

```
col1 | col2 | col3   | col4
------+------+--------+-----------
ghi  | 23   | data1  | otherdata1
ghi  | 23   | data2  | otherdata2
ghi  | 23   | data3  | otherdata3
jkl  | 58   | data4  | otherdata4
stu  | 41   | data5  | otherdata5
stu  | 41   | data6  | otherdata6
stu  | 41   | data7  | otherdata7
```

Result:

```
 col1 | col2 | col3   | col4
 ------+------+--------+-----------
 jkl  | 58   | data4  | otherdata4
```

Thanks

Comment: Linux is an operating system written in C, do you wish to do this in C? Or do you have a specific shell, like `bash`, in mind? Or perhaps a terminal?

Comment: Are the rows with same names always grouped together?

Comment: Thanks Jonny, I can have in shell using awk it will much better than C

Comment: Thanks choroba.  The example one and two are the same file. I believe that the final result would be the result from example one.

Comment: You want 2 different outputs?

Comment: Also, what should happen if the maximum is repeated several times?

Comment: Thanks anubhava. NO, only one output. The example one and two are the same file. I believe that the final result would be the result from example one.

Comment: Thanks choroba again. if the maximum value is repeated several times I need to exclude it too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this awk command:

```
awk 'NR<=2{print; next} $2>max[$1]{max[$1]=$2; a[$1]=$0} END{for (i in a) print a[i]}' file

col1 | col2 | col3   | col4
------+------+--------+-----------
ghp  | 25   | data1  | otherdata1
jkl  | 58   | data4  | otherdata4
stp  | 42   | data5  | otherdata5
```

Comment: Thanks so much anubhava. Perfect! it works excellent! Could you explain me briefly what means "NR<=2"?

Comment: `NR<=2{...}` is for printing the 2 header rows as is.